# How to switch from Lepton Theme To Basic Theme in ABP MVC Project

Tags: abp

I generated a MVC project using abp suite with commercial license. It has default Lepton theme, but i would like to switch to basic theme as it is more easy for customization.

Answer (score 6):

Install [Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Basic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Basic) package to your Web project and add `typeof(AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiBasicThemeModule)` in your DependsOn attribute parameters over your YourProjectNameWebModule class.

Then remove `typeof(AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiLeptonThemeModule)` from DependsOn attribute.

```cs
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(BookstoreHttpApiModule),
        typeof(BookstoreApplicationModule),
        typeof(BookstoreEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
        typeof(AbpAutofacModule),
        typeof(AbpIdentityWebModule),
        typeof(AbpAccountPublicWebIdentityServerModule),
        typeof(AbpAuditLoggingWebModule),
        //typeof(LeptonThemeManagementWebModule), // <-- Remove this 
        typeof(SaasHostWebModule),
        typeof(AbpAccountAdminWebModule),
        typeof(AbpIdentityServerWebModule),
        typeof(LanguageManagementWebModule),
        //typeof(AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiLeptonThemeModule), // and remove this
        typeof(TextTemplateManagementWebModule),
        typeof(AbpSwashbuckleModule),
        typeof(AbpAspNetCoreSerilogModule),
        typeof(AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiBasicThemeModule) // <-- Add This line
        )]
    public class BookstoreWebModule : AbpModule
    { 
        // ...
```

Then add following library to your **package.json**

```json
"@abp/aspnetcore.mvc.ui.theme.basic": "^4.4.0"
```

And execute the following cli command to install client-libraries:

```sh
abp install-libs
```

You're ready to run now

Comment: additionally you have to add in the package.json the theme front libs 
 for use this theme , add "@abp/aspnetcore.mvc.ui.theme.basic": "^4.4.0",

Comment: "font" libs....

Comment: Also if you use `abp add-package Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Basic` command, it'll be added automatically.